# Advanced Custom Fields CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a team page built via ACF. I have 5 members and each of them contains a "View Profile" button.

How can I assign a different color code for each of the button using ACF ?

```
 <button style="width:25%; float:right;"><a href="#">View Profile</a>.</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ACF plugin has a color picker field option that you could include in the Team Member field group: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/color-picker/

So you could, in the template, do something like this:

`<a href="#" style="width:25%; float:right; background-color:<?php the_field('button_color'); ?>">View Profile</a>`

Note that I removed your button wrapper, just for clarity. You probably don't really want to wrap an `<a>` within a `<button>`, but I'm guessing you're doing so because of some styling. There's PROBABLY a button class that can be applied to the `<a>` to give it some nicer styling, depending on what theme you're using.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks a lot Greg.